# How do I select geometry of highest rank in PostGIS/PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have two tables in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database i.e., `pt` and `lines`. Table `pt` contains `point geometry` and table `lines` contain `line geometry` and `values (numeric)`. The following query, for every `pt` selects `lines` within 50 meters search distance and projects new point to the line having value > 500.

```
Select distinct on (pt_id)
pt.gid as pt_id,
case when lines.value > 500
then st_closestpoint(lines.geom, pt.geom)
else null
end as new_pt
from
pt
left join lines on
st_dwithin(pt.geom, lines.geom, 50)
order by pt_id;
```

The sample scenario is shown in the following figure:

[image: The sample scenario]

I need to modify above query to add rank/priority condition such that the line with the highest value should have the highest rank and `new_pt` should be projected to this highest ranked line. How can I modify above code so that the query for large data sets, should first assign the ranks to each line and then projects point to the line having highest value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER BY` list should have more expressions, than `DISTINCT ON`. `DISTINCT ON` is used to tell primary key of new dataset, and `ORDER BY` decides which row from the source table(s) gets into the dataset.

Naturally both lists should share a common head.

In your case I think it should be

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pt_id)
  pt.gid AS pt_id,
  CASE
    WHEN lines.value > 500
      THEN st_closestpoint(lines.geom, pt.geom)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS new_pt
FROM
  pt
LEFT JOIN lines
  ON st_dwithin(pt.geom, lines.geom, 50)
ORDER BY pt_id, lines.value DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you. There is no need to add rank then?

Comment: no, the line with highest value will be selected - you don't need rank() here (you could use it, but this way is shorter)